# Node.JS doesn't refresh the Nunjuck template

Tags: node.js, templates

I'm using Node.JS and Nunjuck to make my templates.
When I change something on my .njk files, I have to stop the Node.JS server and start it back again so that the changes reflect on my browser (localhost:80).

Here is how my app.js (server) looks like:

```
var app = require("express")(),
nunjucks = require('nunjucks'),
server = require("http").createServer(app),
io = require("socket.io").listen(server)
path = require("path");

nunjucks.configure('views', 
{
autoescape: true,
express: app
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) 
{
res.render(__dirname + "/views/index.njk");
});

server.listen(80);
```

And in my index.njk, I have two lines:
`{% set x = 5 %}` and `{{ x }}`.

For example, when I change the value of 5 to 7, I have to restart my node.JS server and then refresh the page in order to get a 7. If I just refresh the page without restarting the server, I still get a 5.

Comment: use `nodemon` or any tool that will watch for changes in any of your project files and then auto restart the server for you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nodemon?
If not do this:

```
npm i -D nodemon
```

than on your package.json do the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon LOCATION/OF/index.js"
  }
```

now you have to run `npm rum start` to build you project.

On "LOCATION/OF/index.js" should be something like: nodemon src/index.js

Nodemon https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nodemon doesn't watch for changes in .njk files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodemon
By default, watching extensions for changes: js,json,md
Here's how to [add .njk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67020468)
Then run these commands:

```
npm install nodemon -g
nodemon app.js
```