# Nodemon - specifying extension watch list using config files

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Is there a way to specify watch list using config files instead of command line?

---

Command line method in nodemon's doc:

[image: nodemon github]

---

I attempted to use a `nodemon.json` config file with the following:

```
{ 
"ext": ["js", "json", "hbs", "html"]
}
```

*Returned an 'extension.match' error.*

Then I tried to add the config to `package.json` with the below:

```
{...
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": ["js", "json", "hbs", "html"]
  }
...}
```

*Also same error.*

I have a feeling both approaches are on the right track, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a `nodemon.json` file in the root of your application you were almost there but the syntax is slightly different to what you had the correct syntax would look like this:

```json
{
    "ext": "js,json,hbs,html"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Nodemon ext matches a string rather than an array.

Answer (score 7):

Nodemon also supports using `package.json` for configuration, under `nodemonConfig` key.

The config is in the same format as in the `nodemon.json` config file:

**package.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": "js,json,hbs,html",
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: First you add nodemon.json file in the root of your project.
(For example if you have a Weather-App Project first you add nodemon.json in the root.)

```
      Weather-App _
                   |_ nodemon.json
```

Step 2:  Add this code in newly created nodemon.json file.

```
        {
          "ext": "js,json,hbs,html,css"
        }
```